# React router order of routes, does it matter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I set up my react router like this:

```
<Route exact path="/users">
    <component/>
</Route>
<Route exact path="/users/:id">
    <component/>
</Route>
```

And it wasn't working correctly (url was changing but content wasn't)
after I changed the order of Route in my Routes.js (the one with :id first) it started working. Do it matters or there is other problem somewhere in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to check

`Route` and
`Switch`

`<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

Read and explore more at https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: Thank you for answer, now I understand how it works :)

Comment: This link returns a 404 and there doesn't seem to be any reference to "switch" in the docs.

Comment: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch
The docs link for the version has changed

Comment: If you are using v6, switch is replaced by Routes https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Comment: In v6 the order does not matter, see [ranked route matching](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#ranked-route-matching)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nested routes should be above its parent.

So in the following code, about/user has to be above /about. If its beneath then only /about will render

```
<Route path='about/user' />
<Router path='about/' />
```

Answer (score -1):

***Basic React Router Setup***

```js
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Please add explanation so that the community can understand easily. Especially new comers.